# C# create file with text

Tags: c#, filestream, streamwriter

I have problem with the FileStream. I want to create a file with my custom name, but it doesn't work. What I doing wrong ?

```
string nameoftest = Console.ReadLine()+".txt";
string path = "C:\C#test\" + nameoftest;
Console.WriteLine(path);
FileStream create = new FileStream(@"path", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(create);
```

Comment: Use the variable  `path` like `FileStream create = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);`

Comment: This is a good time to start to learn to read error messages and use the debugger.  Also the MSDN documentation for functions, which often includes example code.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What *does* it do?  What do you *expect* it to do?  Why?

Comment: Hint: Not all characters are valid characters in a Windows file path.

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance on posting code  and [edit] post to provide real compilable sample along with exact error messages. "Code" in the post can't even compile due to totally broken string constant.

Comment: Also using `@"path"` to pass value of variable *may* indicate that you need some more time with basic tutorial/book...

Comment: Don't you need to escape the '\' to '\\'

Comment: Avoid Special Character.If u want Unique file name use current datetime along with filename and try following `using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"<file path>\Output.txt", true))
                    {
                        file.WriteLine(<text string>);
                    }`

Answer (score 3):

There are some mistakes in your code.

- You should specify a valid path
- You should pass `path` parameter for `FileStream`
- You could use `sw.WriteLine` after declaring `StreamWriter`
- It could be better to use `using` blocks to dispose streams when you finish your job

The code looks like

```
string nameoftest = Console.ReadLine() + ".txt";
string path = @"C:\" + nameoftest;
Console.WriteLine(path);
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
{
    sw.WriteLine("WriteSomething");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the @ sign is misplaced

The error is in 2 lines:

> string path = "C:\C#test\" + nameoftest;

Should be

> string path = @"C:\C#test\" + nameoftest;

The second error is:

> FileStream create = new FileStream(@"path", FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
>   FileAccess.ReadWrite);

Should be

> FileStream create = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
>   FileAccess.ReadWrite);